# Define a globally available constant (across dependencies) in Angular

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I would like to declare a constant in an angular module that is available to a module that has been injected into it. Is there some kind of inheritance such that dependencies can be passed and freely used variables/constants from the module that is dependent on them?

Thus, if I have

```
angular.module(project_module);
module.constant("cats", "hans");

angular.module(project_module, ['dependencyA', function(dependencyA) {})]);
```

I want the constant "cats" to be available for use in the dependencyA. How can I pass it in?

Comment: Just like any other dependency.:  function(dependencyA, cats)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the name of the module as a dependency to another module then you can access its constant or any other properties there.

```
var app1=angular.module("project_module",[]);
app.constant("cats", "hans");

var app2=angular.module("project_module1", ["project_module"]);
```